# Custom css button div issue

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to figure out why this custom css button I made, ONLY likes being within a div tag. Currently if I use a div for the button, I can not have anything else on the same line as the button without doing some css position stuff. If I have to as a last resort I will do that, but I want to see IF I can use another element, and why my button freaks out when you replace the div with anything else.
You can take a look at the code here and see what I'm not seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/takkun/k1pz75t2/

```
<div class="Gcheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="Gcheckbox" name="check" />
<label for="Gcheckbox"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want next to it....

Comment: What exactly is your issue? And how are you going about in using a div as a button? But the reason things are not inline is because div is block level and needs to be changed so it doesn't break lines. Also, have you thought about using the button tag?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that other elements won't work as wrappers as that they don't have the right styles to maintain the height you've set on the element. A span would work just fine if you also set `display: inline-block;` on it.

As to other items not being on the same line, that's how `block` elements work by default: they take up as much space as they can width-wise. If you want other items on the same line you can set it to be `inline-block` like the previous span example or you can set it to be `float: left;`, etc. Whatever suits your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a style `display: inline-block` to the `.Gcheckbox`. That way, it will be able to be inserted in the flow of the text, but still render as an inline element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k1pz75t2/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the `block` behavior of the `div` tag to have another elements aside. You can change it to `inline-block`:

```
.Gcheckbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* ROUNDED ONE */

.Gcheckbox {
  /*CHANGES GRAY SQUARE DIMENSIONS*/
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 33px;
  background: #ff0000;
  /*GRAY SQUARE BACKGROUND FADER*/
  background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 0000ff 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
  /* margin: 0px auto;*/
  position: relative;
}
.Gcheckbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /*MAKES THE GREEN CIRCLE A CIRCLE*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /********************************/
  left: 3px;
  top: 11.25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239, 239, 238, 1);
  /*BEHIND GREEN CIRCLE BACKGROUND*/
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0000ff', endColorstr='#0000ff', GradientType=1);
}
.Gcheckbox label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00bf00;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42, 171, 43);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42, 171, 43);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42, 171, 43);
}
/*CHANGE HOVER EFFECT OPACITY*/

.Gcheckbox label:hover::after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.Gcheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gcheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="Gcheckbox" name="check" />
  <label for="Gcheckbox"></label>
</div>
<h2>I'm aside the button</h2>
```

Also with that property on the classname you can use any other tag like `span` since now has the property to make the dimensions `width` and `height` to work.